# Connecting to MongoDB to be used in UIPath

Tags: mongodb, uipath

I am trying to connect to MongoDB so I can use it in UIPath but there are no APIs available other than DB administrative APIs.  I want to manipulate the actual data in the data table.  How can I do this, other than creating a robot that manipulates the table directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB Atlas, which is Cloud based, does not have ANY CRUD APIs.  In MongoDB Server side, the CRUD APIs are deprecated so for sure they will not have it in the cloud version.

Unfortunately, you will need to go through a third party to connect to MongoDB.  Luckily there are a few out there.  The one I like to use is PrestoAPI.

Got to the PrestoAPI Website: https://prestoapi.com/
Click on get started for free

Fill out the user data, select if this is for personal or business and then select Free
There will be a confirmation email sent
Confirm your email, (you may have to resend the confirmation link) and then sign in
Once you log in, you will see this:

Click on Connect to A Database
Click again to get this pop up
All information needed is in the connection string we got from MongoDB
Driver is MongoDB
We will use the database Sample_airbnb from the database sample

Click on test

Once it says connection successful, we can move on
FYI, sometimes PrestoAPI will drop the “+srv” from the beginning of the connection string.  Ensure that this part is correct or recopy again from MongoDB
You will get this result
Go back to the dashboard and click on Create a project

You should see the AirBNB name
Click on Submit
Next, select “Create your first endpoint”

It will give you a list to go through.  Ensure you pick the name of the Endpoint (you only get 10 of them)
Select the database, the component (Table) and the table you want to read

For now, everything else can stay as default but you can always go back and tweak them
Once complete, click Submit. You now have a list of usable CRUD APIs for your MongoDB Atlas

You can now use these end points and call them in Node.js, UIPath or wherever a regular REST API can be called

Answer (score 0):

You can use Invoke code activity. Here is the detailed step-by-step [answer](https://forum.uipath.com/t/uipath-and-mongodb-connectivity/234061/2?u=theraga)